# What is the equivalence of Virtualenv on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, virtualenv

Please I want to create  a virtual enviroment on MacOS similar to the way I use virtual env in ubuntu. Please what is the right command to use?

Thanks

Comment: Are you having trouble using virutalenv on macOS? It works the same as on Ubuntu. You just need to install it. What issues are you running into? macOS support is discussed in the installation docs. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Thanks for you selfless response. I was told I would need virtualenvwrapper  in additon to virtualenv on macOs..can you throw more light on that?

Comment: virtualenvwrapper is just a set of extensions on virtualenv. I've used them on Mac, but they're not required. They're not specific to Mac. You can use virtualenvwrapper on any virtualenv platform as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

The MacOS terminal is also a linux terminal so you should be able to use the same command in both Mac and Ubuntu terminals.

Comment: It's true that it's the same command, but it's not Linux. macOS is built on Darwin, which is a very different, but still "unix-like," OS. (But totally agree that it will work. It can just be confusing if people think they can follow Linux-specific instructions on macOS.)